# how should I change this code to display empty regions?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Please help me to change this code to show items that their count=0
and also I want to add space between name and count

```
$args = array('hide_empty=0');

$terms = get_terms('job_region', $args);
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
$count = count($terms);
$i = 0;
$term_list = '<ul class="statelist clearfix">';
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $i++;
    $term_list. = '<li count-all='.$term - > count.
    '><a href="/job-search/?location='.$term - > name.
    '&submit=true" title="'.esc_attr(sprintf(__('نمایش آگهی های %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term - > name)).
    '">'.$term - > name.
    '('.$term - > count.
    ')'.
    '</a></li>';
    if ($count != $i) {
        $term_list. = " ";
    } else {
        $term_list. = '</ul>';
    }
}
echo $term_list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:-

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'job_region',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
$count = count($terms);
$i = 0;
$term_list = '<ul class="statelist clearfix">';
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $i++;
    $term_list. = '<li count-all='.$term - > count.
    '><a href="/job-search/?location='.$term - > name.
    '&submit=true" title="'.esc_attr(sprintf(__('نمایش آگهی های %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term - > name)).
    '">'.$term - > name.
    ' ('.$term - > count.
    ')'.
    '</a></li>';
    if ($count != $i) {
        $term_list. = " ";
    } else {
        $term_list. = '</ul>';
    }
}
echo $term_list;
}
```

You can read more @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/